# How to update the weights of a ranking algorithms through unsupervised learning?

Tags: recommender-system, unsupervised-learning

I have, let's say, 100 samples with n features, and I want to rank them by learning the weights for each feature. Weights must be learned from implicit ratings from the user (eg. user click). However, I want the learning itself to be unsupervised. For example, I want to learn the weights for each feature from only the samples for which the previous rating is present (the positive class). Due to the high imbalance between positive and negative classes, I don't want to apply any supervised learning algorithm.

Can someone suggest some ways to accomplish this?